# Через консольное приложение запустить строку cmd и выполнить там определенную команду

Tags: c#, cmd

Нужно через консольное приложение запустить строку cmd и выполнить там определенную команду (конкретно dir /s /b (путь) (сохранить в txt файл), после чего закрыть cmd и продолжить работу в моем приложении. Подскажите, как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

Для запуска процесса следует использовать класс Process

```
String arguments = "/C dir /s /b C:\\ > C:\\Users\\user\\dir_result.txt";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", arguments);
proc.WaitForExit(); //ожидаем завершения выполнения команды
... //код, который выполняется после завершения команды
```